# How to fix a horizontal navigation page doesn't properly resize?

Tags: resize, navigation, scroll, scale

Please go to: http://morningside.cardboardmonet.com/

Notice that the website drag scrolls from left to right, however when you resize the window it doesn't scale-- the page just goes blank. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is considered bad form to ask us to visit your site to "see what's wrong".  You will get a much better response if you first attempt to narrow down the issue to a specific piece of code on your site.  Then post the code along with a specific question about the piece you don't understand, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chacelove, please add this piece of code to your js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initDrag();
});
//
function resize_adjustments() {
    $("#proof").css('width', '100%');
    $("#proof").css('height', '100%');
    $("#proof > div").each(function(i) {
        if($(this).css('left') == "0px") {
            current = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).css('left', '0');
        } else {
            $(this).css('left', $("#proof").width()+"px");
        }
    });
}
var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resize_adjustments, 500);
});
```

did it work?

Comment: don't forget to remove the $(window).resize(function() {..., ok?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Maybe I've added it wrong, but it breaks the dragging function...